# What does the _Get method of a std::weak_ptr do and when should it be used?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I was reading about smart pointers, weak pointers in particular. I understood that weak pointers do not have a similar `get()` method like shared pointers, because it's uncertain whether the weak pointer is pointing at anything. Then I found that Intellisence suggested `_Get()` method.

What exactly does the `_Get()` method of std::weak_ptr do, and when should it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never. Underscore-capital-letter names are reserved for the implementation. You, as a user, are not supposed to use them, ever. Furthermore, it is not listed in [`weak_ptr`'s interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), so code written depending on it would not be portable.

As for what it does: it probably is some helper function. Since it's reserved for the implementation for *any use*, it makes little sense to delve into it further, as it is allowed to change (or disappear) between even minor versions.

> N4140 § 17.6.4.3.2 [global.names] / 1
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
>   the implementation: —  Each name that contains a double underscore
>   `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter
>   (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.

Comment: Why is the function public?

Comment: @oddRaven I don't know. Maybe it makes sense in the standard library shipped with your compiler. It definitely shouldn't be shown as a code completion suggestion to you, though.